# Ordering Table by column

Tags: forms, 8

I try to add the possibility to order by column in the header of my table element.

I started to use Drupal 8 and I can't find any clear documentation about table on the API site to do what i want...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do this while defining the header array like

```
$header = array(
     array(
       'data'  => t('Url'),
       'field' => 'd.path',
       'sort'  => 'asc',
     ),
     array(
       'data'  => t('Text'),
       'field' => 'd.text',
     ),
    );
```

So, this table will have two columns, Url & Text. And it will be sorted in ascending order by column Url.